Is $\mathfrak p$ a maximal ideal of $B$?
In the section 2.8 of Lei Fu's "Etale Cohomology Theory", the author introduces a term "essentialy etale":

A local homomorphism $A\to A'$ is called essentially etale if there exists an etale $A$-algebra $B$ and a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $B$ lying above the maximal ideal of $A$ such that $A'$ is $A$-isomorphic to $B_\mathfrak{p}$.

Because $\operatorname{Spec}B\to\operatorname{Spec}A$ is etale, it is quasi-finite, then $\mathfrak p$ must be a maximal ideal of $B$, mustn't it?

Quasi-finite isn't as good as finite.
Based on the fact you highlighted (quasi)finiteness, you seem to be invoking a principle from commutative algebra about integrally closed extensions... which is valid for finite ring maps, not ring maps of finite type. Specifically, if $f:A\to B$ makes $B$ a finite $A$-algebra, then it is true that $\phi:\mathrm{Spec}(B)\to\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ (is a proper map and) has $\phi(x)$ closed iff. $x$ is closed, or that $f^{-1}\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal if and only if $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal.
For $A/f^{-1}\mathfrak{p}\hookrightarrow B/\mathfrak{p}$ would be an integrally closed extension of integral domains, and one of the two is a field iff. the other one is i.e. one of the ideals is maximal iff. the other is. But if $B$ is merely a finitely generated $A$-algebra (as opposed to a finitely generated $A$-module, which is what finiteness of $f$ would mean) then we can't make any such conclusions.
